# Combining Countif with Date

Tags: excel-formula

I am creating a spreadsheet to analyse UK horse racing.  I have 4 columns.
Column A is the race date.
Column B is the name of the course meeting on race date shown in Column A
Column C is a list of all UK race courses
Column D is a calculation showing the total number of meetings per course.
Column D uses the formula =COUNTIF($B$2:$B1176,$C2)

I would like to add another column "E" which shows the number of meetings remaining as each meeting concludes.  e.g. at the start of the year there are 25 meetings at Ascot.  After each meeting the number remaining would reduce by 1

The logic for the new column would be:
If Column A is todays date find the course name shown in column B, match with the same course in Column C, then reduce the numnber of remaining meetings by the total number of meetings which have already taken place and show in Column E.

The objective is to show the number of remaining meetings as the year progresses.

Thanks

Dave

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Pro tip: show at least some effort to solve your own problem if you want to get the answer. Also provide some example data so that folks would understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Use the COUNTIFS function with TODAY as below:

=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$1176,$C$1,$A$2:$A$1176,">="&TODAY())

COUNTIFS allows you to count based on multiple criteria so in this case by the race meeting and the date, also using the less than or equal combine with today, is basically only returning the matching meeting where the date is less than or equal to the current date, thus giving you those remaining.

You could also think about turning the data set into a table to allow the formula to dynamically change as you enter new data.

I have a full tutorial on this you can check out http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1nLTDk2QLL9415OPSjIICJs1EeV-HeK3

Hope it helps